# Find all perfect squares in two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Two number sequences defined as:
$$a_1=b_1=1,$$ $$a_k=3a_{k-1}+4b_{k-1},\quad b_k=2a_{k-1}+3b_{k-1}\quad \forall 2\le k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$$

Is it possible to find all $k$s that make $a_k$ perfect squares?

**update**

It is possible to find that:

$$a_n=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(\left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right)^{n-1}-\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)^n\right),\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$$

Comment: Have you found any examples (other than $k=1$)?

Comment: Hint : first note that $a_k^2-2b_k^2=-1$...

Comment: @Mike Bennett What is the rest?

Comment: $a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-a_n$, which gives $a_n$, which is very ugly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg it is also true that $b_{n+2} = 6 b_{n+1} - b_n.$ This is Cayley-Hamilton for the given 2 by 2 coefficient matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to fill in the early parts, the given coefficient matrix  is an "automorphism" of the quadratic form $x^2 - 2 y^2.$ That is,
$$ (3x+4y)^2 - 2 (2x+3y)^2 = x^2 - 2 y^2. $$
So, starting with $a_1^2 - 2 b_1^2,$ we will always get the same value for $a_j^2 - 2 b_j^2.$

Next, the trace is $6$ and determinant $1,$ if we call the matrix
$$
A = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 4 \\
2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we get, by Cayley-Hamilton.
$$ A^2 - 6 A + I = 0 $$
We also get
$$ a_{n+2} = 6 a_{n+1} - a_n, $$
$$ b_{n+2} = 6 b_{n+1} - b_n. $$

The end, which i may not be able to supply, is usually unique factorization, in this case in the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q [\sqrt 2].$ i will see if it is in Mordell's book.

==========================================

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   4
    2   3
  Automorphism backwards:  
    3   -4
    -2   3

  3^2 - 2 2^2 = 1

 u^2 - 2 v^2 = -1

Tue Jun 20 15:15:12 PDT 2017

u:  1  v:  1 ratio: 1  SEED   KEEP +- 
u:  7  v:  5 ratio: 1.4
u:  41  v:  29 ratio: 1.41379
u:  239  v:  169 ratio: 1.4142
u:  1393  v:  985 ratio: 1.41421
u:  8119  v:  5741 ratio: 1.41421
u:  47321  v:  33461 ratio: 1.41421
u:  275807  v:  195025 ratio: 1.41421
u:  1607521  v:  1136689 ratio: 1.41421
u:  9369319  v:  6625109 ratio: 1.41421
u:  54608393  v:  38613965 ratio: 1.41421

Tue Jun 20 15:17:12 PDT 2017

 u^2 - 2 v^2 = -1

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

=======================

Comment: I can find that $a_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(\left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right)^{n-1}-\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)^n\right)$,but don't know how to do the next step.

Comment: @LCFactorization it would appear that Mordell's book says that there is just one solution when BOTH $a,b$ are squares. Even then, he does not write it all out.

Comment: May I have the book name ?

Comment: @lc Diophantine Equations (1969).

Comment: So finding the square values of the $b_k$ amounts to an old problem, solved by Ljunggren in the 1940s. There is no known "easy" solution, but the only square values are $1$ and $169$. The squares in the $a_k$ sequence (or, equivalently, the equation $x^4-2y^2=-1$) are much easier to find -- see Mordell, page 18. $a_k=1$ is the only one.

Comment: @MikeBennett thank you.